# Example of function in $H^1(U)$ which is not continuous, where $U \subset R^2$ has a smooth boundary.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Does anyone have a nice geometric example of function in $H^1(U)$ which is not continuous, where $U \subset R^2$ and has a smooth boundary. I want something that is easy to remember.

Comment: Take a smooth function on the disc (even continuous to the boundary) and change it arbitrarily at a single point, so that it has a removable singularity. Is this enough, or do you want to specify some more pathological behavior?

Comment: I don't want the function to be in an equivalence class with a continuous function.

Comment: Ok. See the answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569390/function-always-continuous-in-a-sobolev-space.

Comment: Ok thanks alot.